# Solving functional equation; $f(x+y)=yf(x)+f(y)$ also given that $f(1)=2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives, functional-equations

> **Question:** If the function $f(x)$ satisfies the relation $(f(x+y)=yf(x)+f(y))$ with $f(1)=2$, then $\lim_{x\to 1^+}f'(x)$ is:
>   Domain of function is $(1,\infty)$

I need to find $f'(1)$ to solve this question.
But can't seem to find the solution of the equation.
Now this functional equation is giving me problems.
Solving functions without calculus is often too easy for me but idk why this is hard. Maybe this requires calculus.

Till now I've tried putting $1$ at the places of $x$ and $y$ and then trying to solve which results in $x=1$.
Calculus doesn't help in my case. I tried differentiating which resulted in long differential equation which simplified to $x=1$ again. XD

Thank you.

Comment: On which domain is $f$ defined?

Comment: $1^{+}$ and in real numbers.

Comment: What is $1^+$? Do you mean the interval $[1, \infty)$?

Comment: Martin yes but with open brackets both side.

Comment: @LoveInvariants But you have $f(1)=2$. So it isn't open in both directions.

Comment: yep but it is disjointed like $f(1)=2$ and then the rest for $(1,\infty)$ obv can't be disjointed as limit exists.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, there is no such function. Setting $y=1$ gives $f(x+1) = f(x) + 2$, so that $f(2) = 4$, $f(3) = 6$. Then set $x=1, y=2$ to get a contradiction: $6 = f(1+2) = 2f(1) + f(2) = 8$.

Answer (score 2):

If we set $y=0$, we get $f(x)=f(0)$. This means that the function is a constant. So, $f(x)=2$. However, this clearly doesn't satisfy the condition set by $x=y=1$, which makes $f(2)=4$, so there is no solution.

**Edit**: Upon OP's comments, where it was specified that the domain of the function is $[1,\infty)$. I don't have a full solution, but here are some thoughts.

Note that by plugging in $x=1$, we have $f(y+1)=2y+f(y)$. So, we have $f(n)=n^2-n+2$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.

When we let $x=y$, our functional equation becomes $f(2x)=(x+1)f(x)$.

So, we will compute $f\left(\frac{2^n+1}{2^n}\right)$ for natural $n$.

Note that $f(2^n+1)=2^{2n}+2^n+2$ for $n\in\mathbb N$

So, $$f\left(\frac{2^n+1}{2^n}\right)=(2^{2n}+2^n+2)\cdot\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{2^i}{2^n+2^i+1}$$So consider the limit as $n\to\infty$.

**Edit 2**: As @MartinR notes, since setting $y=1$ forces the function to be linear, which clearly contradicts the work above, there is no such function.

Comment: but f(0) isn't 2.

Comment: If we let $x=1$, $f(1)=f(0)$.

Comment: oh yes. But the answer was given -2. Shouldn't it be 0.

Comment: Well, unless there's some domain information that you haven't provided, that isn't correct.

Comment: That domain is $1^{+}$

Comment: That would have been good to include. And, also note that the limit must be $\lim\limits_{x\to1^+}$, rather than a full limit.

Comment: @DonThousand: $f(x) = 2$ does not satisfy the given functional equation.

Comment: Ok but does that change the answer? I think no.

Comment: @MartinR OP literally just added more constraints, you gotta give me time to edit.

Comment: @LoveInvariants It completely changes the problem.

Comment: Sorry I had no idea. I was solving without it.

Comment: $y=0$ is not permitted, since $0$ does NOT belong to the domain of $f$

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I'm aware. I'm editing as of the moment, since OP edited that in after I answered. See comments above.

Comment: @DonThousand: My point is that $f(x) = 2$ does not solve the functional equation, regardless of the constraints. You are right that the domain should be been specified correctly, but if $y=0$ were permitted  then the answer would be *“there is no such function.”*

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I agree. I'm still editing.

Comment: @DonThousand: Unless I am mistaken, there is no such function, see my comment at the question. Or did I make some error?

Comment: @MartinR Good catch. It's 4 am where I am, so clearly my brain isn't functioning.

Answer (score 2):

There is no function $f$ with $f(1) = 2$ and $f(x+y) = yf(x) + f(y)$ for $x, y \ge 1$.

Setting $y=1$ gives $f(x+1) = f(x) + 2$, so that $f(2) = 4$ and $f(3) = 6$.

Then set $x=1, y=2$ to get a contradiction: $6 = f(1+2) = 2f(1) + f(2) = 8$.

Comment: Maybe d option is correct which is not defined but answer is written as -2.

Comment: can't there be system of equations

Comment: @LoveInvariants: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. You asked about  a function having certain properties, not about a system of equations. If your real problem is not what you wrote above then I suggest that you update the question, or post a new one.

Comment: Nope can't there be system of functions with same derivative at x=1. The questions asks limit of derivative at 1 no?

Comment: @LoveInvariants: Your question asks for the $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$ and not for the limit of the derivative. But if there is no function satisfying the given conditions then there is no limit. – Are you sure that you quoted the problem fully and correctly?

Comment: holy shit again. My mistake again. Why do I keep doing these mistakes in my questions? Btw edited.

Comment: @LoveInvariants Your edit only changes the question to be about the *derivative* of a non-existant function rather than the function itself! *There is no function $f$ satisfying your condition.* Unless you change the functional equation itself, asking any further questions about a non-existant function satisfying it will remain meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try the definition of the derivative. $$f’(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}{f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}$$

$$=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}{hf(x)+f(h)-f(x)\over h}$$

Another route you could try is since the expression $f(x+y)$ is symmetric in $x,y$ but the RHS is not, 
$$yf(x)+f(y)-xf(y)-f(x)=0$$

$$f(x)(y-1)+f(y)(1-x)=0$$

This would indicate $f(x)=k(x-1)$ since $\frac{f(x)}{f(y)}= \frac{x-1}{y-1}$ and $f(x)$ doesn’t depend on $y$. But, in this case, even when taking limits, $f(1) \not = 2$ and $f(1)\not = -2$. Hence a contradiction. (It has been shown in another way by Martin R at the time of making this edit).  It is anyway unclear what the question means by $f(1)=2$ when $1$ is not in the domain of $f(x)$.

Comment: ok. Let me try then I will accept.

Comment: This doesn't work, since for $h<1$, $f(h)$ is not defined.

Comment: Darn. Missed that. Added another route.

Comment: still this doesn't help me.

Comment: What does $f(1)=2$ mean since it’s given that $1$ isn’t in the domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can show that the only function $ f $ with $ f : ( 1 , + \infty ) \to \mathbb C $ and
$$ f ( x + y ) = y f ( x ) + f ( y ) \tag 0 \label 0 $$
is the constant zero function. To see this, substitute $ x $ for $ y $ and $ y $ for $ x $ in \eqref{0} to get $ f ( y + x ) = x f ( y ) + f ( x ) $. Combining this with \eqref{0} and rearranging the terms, we have $ ( y - 1 ) f ( x ) = ( x - 1 ) f ( y ) $. Letting $ y = 2 $ in this eqation, we have
$$ f ( x ) = f ( 2 ) ( x - 1 ) \text . \tag 1 \label 1 $$
Now, if we let $ x = 3 $ and $ y = 2 $ in \eqref{0} we'll have $ f ( 5 ) = 2 f ( 3 ) + f ( 2 ) $, which combining with \eqref{1} shows that $ 4 f ( 2 ) = 5 f ( 2 ) $. Thus $ f ( 2 ) = 0 $, which using \eqref{1} gives what was claimed.
Therefore $ f $ is differentiable everywhere with $ f ' ( x ) = 0 $ for every $ x $ in $ ( 1 , + \infty ) $. In particular, you get $ \lim _ { x \to 1 ^ + } f ' ( x ) = 0 $.

As the domain of $ f $ is $ ( 1 , + \infty ) $, $ f ( 1 ) $ has no meaning. But if you rephrase the question so that the domain of $ f $ is $ [ 1 , + \infty ) $ with $ f ( 1 ) $ equal to anything, for example $ f ( 1 ) = 2 $, and ask for the functional equation \eqref{0} to hold only for $ x , y \in ( 1 , + \infty ) $ and not for every $ x $ and $ y $ in the domain, it will make sense, and the answer is as above. If you want \eqref{0} to hold for every $ x $ and $ y $ in the domain $ [ 1 , + \infty ) $, the same reasoning forces you to have $ f ( 1 ) = 0 $, as \eqref{1} says so.